# Is it possible to build JNI .dll under Linux?

Tags: java, linux, maven, java-native-interface, maven-nar-plugin

I'm using nar-maven-plugin 3.0.0
My pom resemble following:

```
<packaging>nar</packaging>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
            <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <libraries>
                    <library>
                        <type>jni</type>
                    </library>
                </libraries>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And it actually works. Under my Linux it automatically finds gcc and use it to build everything and package it into nar. However this is .so file.

And my question is: Is it possible to configure it somehow to create **under Linux** nar with .dll next to nar with .so? And in general to produce JNI nars, to diffrent architectures?

If it possible please provide some configuration snippet, link or anything which can give me some clue.

Answer (score 2):

1. Copy the Windows JDK onto linux. Elsewise, you won't have needed headers and implibs. If you look, you will see that there are two JNI header files; one is *per-platform*. And, of course, you need an implib to link your DLL so that it can connect up to the JVM.
2. Get https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/MinGW?rd=SIGs/MinGW, a cross-compiler environment.
3. Teach the NAR plugin about (2). This might take some reading of the source of the NAR plugin.
4. Mourn that you still need a Windows box to *test the results*.

So are you sure you want to do this? I very much doubt that you will find that this is a common, supported, practice, because most of us want to test the things that we build. Since you need actual Windows to test, you might as well build there.

Comment: 1. I thought that headers are common since JNI is a standard. And what is reason to link to implementation at compile time? I want to link to it at run time.

2. Thanks, I will use apt

3. You meant Learn? I don't want to read source, I'm searching whether someone do it before me and has some USEFUL hints to pass. Obviously it isn't you.

4. Not me. I'm developer. I don't want to hold VM with Windows + Mac + Android + ... just to compile library. I just compile it and send to 3-4 testers each of them have diffrent environment.

Yes. I'm sure.

Comment: @abc 1. No, the file `jni_md.h` is different per platform. That's what it's for. You don't need to link unless you are using elements of the Invocation API. 2. Don't make offensive comments to people who are trying to help you. You may have to contribute more to solving your own problem than you may have first thought. This isn't anybody else's fault.

Comment: @EJP I didn't mean to make offensive comment. If it sounds so it's by accident. Anyway I already solved problem thanks to pointing out your `jni_md.h` is different per platform. I just copied it from `include/win32` into linux and build jni dll which works like charm. I use c `make` though since this plugin seems not to support multiple output files. I will post complete how-to in few days because of lack of time at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it requires a cross compiler for each platform you wish to traget.  Your Jar's build process will also need to be cross-compiler aware.

Comment: Emm... very general. Any example?
Let's assume I will install MinGW, does plugin find it and create .dll? Or additional configuration is needed?

Comment: Use toolPath under cpp and linker to specify the location of your cross toolchain.  I believe you can use the nar.arch property to specify the target arch as well.